# XP: Scan virus/malware from all accounts or just admin?

Tags: windows-xp, virus, limited-user-account

I have one admin account and one limited user account.

If I just scan for virus/malware from my admin account, will that also scan my other account? Or do I need to login to my limited user account to scan again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Single scan from admin should do the job.  Just be sure to scan the whole drive(s).